# Payment Information on hook_commerce_checkout_complete

Tags: commerce

I am developing module which connects Drupal Commerce with 3rd party invoicing system. For this purpose I need to send payment information (has it been paid? how much? in what way?) after the order is complete. I guess the `hook_commerce_checkout_complete()` hook is the best place to do that but I can't figure out how to obtain this payment information from an `$order` object/entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the payment method the customer selected in the $order->data array, and to determine if the order was paid in full you'd use commerce_payment_order_balance(). Any additional information would have to come from payment transaction entities whose order_id match $order->order_id.